# function Z is not defined при выполнении процедуры в firebird

Tags: firebird

**Дано:**
.exe программа, которая использует файл **.fdb**  и в папке с программой есть драйвера firebird (.dll файлы)

**Задача:** получить данные из файла .fdb

Я установил себе firebird-сервер. 
Подключился к файлу .fdb.
Данные получил, все ок.

Кроме этого, я там нашел процедуру, которую хочу выполнить.

Но при выполнении процедуры, я получаю ошибку:

> function Z is not  defined; module name or entrypoint could not be
>   found; Error  while parsing procedure **********'s BLR
>   [SQLState:HY000, ISC  error code:335544343] Error Code: 335544343

я предполагаю, что при выполнении этой процедуры в .exe файле, там есть некая функция **Z**

А когда я конекчусь к файлу **.fdb** через свой локальный сервер firebird, то функции **Z** нет.

**Вопрос:** где эта функция **Z** может быть описана непосредственно в .exe файле или в каких-либо .dll файлах?

И как я могу подключиться к .fdb-файлу, что бы процедуру можно было выполнить?

Исходный текст тела процедуры затерт. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ**: Внешние/пользовательские функции, они же User Defined Function (UDF) описываются в DLL, лежащих рядом с сервером. Подробнее нужно смотреть в настройках вашей версии сервера.

**Дополнение:**

Во времена Firebird 1.0 из-за очень ограниченного функционала встроенных функций энтузиасты разработали библиотеку [rfunc](http://rfunc.sourceforge.net/rus/), содержащую большое количество UDF-функций для Firebird. В этой библиотеке есть и функция [Z()](http://rfunc.sourceforge.net/rus/rfunc.htm)

Проверить, что это действительно на можно запросом:

```
SELECT F.RDB$MODULE_NAME, F.RDB$ENTRYPOINT FROM RDB$FUNCTIONS F WHERE F.RDB$FUNCTION_NAME = 'Z'
```

Если `RDB$ENTRYPOINT = 'fn_z'`, то это скорее всего она. `RDB$MODULE_NAME` содержит имя dll без расширения.

Comment: именно так, как вы описали. спасибо!